# Проблема с алгоритмом слияния. Помогите разобраться

Tags: c, алгоритм

В статье [Stable Minimum Storage Merging by Symmetric
Comparisons](http://ak.hanyang.ac.kr/papers/esa2004.pdf) приведен псевдокод алгоритма, по которому я написал программу на С ([код здесь](http://zalil.ru/32698423)).

Она не работает (результат слияния 2-х упорядоченных массивов не упорядочен).

**Собственно, вопросы:**

1. Я ошибся в перекодировании алгоритма с псевдокода на C ?
2. или я чего-то не понял в статье и приведенный алгоритм в принципе не работает ? (с чего бы это ?)

Алгоритм

Algorithm 1 Symmerge algorithm

```
Symmerge (A, first1, first2, last)
  if first1 < first2 and first2 < last then
    m <-  (first1 + last)/2
    n <-  m + first2
    if first2 > m then
      start <-  Bsearch (A, n - last, m, n - 1)
    else
      start <-  Bsearch (A, first1, first2, n - 1)
    end <-  n - start
    Rotate (A, start, first2, end)
    Symmerge (A, first1, start, m)
    Symmerge (A, m, end, last)

Bsearch (A, l, r, p)
  while l < r
    m <-  (l + r ) / 2
    if A[m] <= A[p - m]
      then l   m + 1 ;
      else r   m;
  return l
```

Часть кода, соответствующая алгоритму

```
Symmerge (int A[], int first1, int first2, int last)
{
  printf ("Symm %d %d %d\n",first1,first2,last);
  int start, end, m, n;

  if (first1 < first2 && first2 < last) {
    m = (first1 + last)/2;
    n =  m + first2;
    if (first2 > m) {
      start =  Bsearch (A, n - last, m, n - 1);
    } else { 
      start =  Bsearch (A, first1, first2, n - 1);
    }
    end = n - start;

    Rotate (A, start, first2, end);
    Symmerge (A, first1, start, m);
    Symmerge (A, m, end, last);
  }
}

int
Bsearch (int A[], int l, int r, int p)
{
  int m;
  while (l < r) {
    m = (l + r ) / 2;
    if (A[m] <= A[p - m])
      l =   m + 1 ;
    else r = m;
  }
  return l;
}
```

Функцию Rotate() тестировал (да и в ее коде печать массива до и после есть), крутит нормально.

Вожусь давно, почему не работает (точнее почему **этот** алгоритм должен работать) не понимаю.

В тайне надеюсь, что я что-то не понял в псевдокоде и поэтому не работает.

**UPDATE 1** (на комментарий [[@jmu](/users/1810/jmu)](/users/1810/jmu))

Rotate

Взято [отсюда](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/)

Псевдокод

```
/* Функция swap(a, b, m) меняем местами:
 * x[a..a+m-1] и x[b..b+m-1]
 */

if rotdist == 0 || rotdist == n
  exit

i = p = rotdist
j = n - p
while i != j
  /* инвариант:
     x[0..p-i] двигать не нужно
     x[p-i..p-1] = a (нужно поменять с b)
     x[p..p+j-1] = b (нужно поменять с a)
     x[p+j..n-1] двигать не нужно */

  if i > j
    swap(p-i, p, j)
    i -= j
  else
    swap(p-i, p+j-i, i)
    j -= i
swap(p-i, p, i)
```

Реализация Rotate

```
void
swap (int a[], int f, int t, int l)
{
  int tt;

  for (l+=f; f < l; f++,t++) {
    tt = a[f];
    a[f] = a[t];
    a[t] = tt;
  }
}

void
rotate (int a[], int n, int dist)
{
  if (dist == 0 || dist == n)
    return;
  int i, j, p;
  i = p = dist;
  j = n - p;
  while (i != j) {
    if (i > j) {
      swap (a, p-i,p,j);
      i -= j;
    } else {
      swap (a, p-i,p+j-i,i);
      j -= i;
    }
  }
  swap (a, p-i,p,i);
}

Rotate (int *A, int left, int r, int end)
{
  int *a = A+left, n = end-left+1, m = r-left;
  printf ("l=%d r=%d e=%d\n",left,r,end);
  pri("++ ");
  rotate (a,n,m);
  pri("-- ");
}
```

Comment: интересно, завтра на работе попробую закодить. добавте пожалуйста еще псевдокод rotate :)

Comment: update1: у меня после выполнения первой ротации результат уже не совпадает с тем что у авторов используется в качестве примера

Comment: Странно, у меня в начальной последовательности

    0 2 5 9 1 4 7 8 

сначала, как и у авторов меняются местами [5 9] с [1 4] 

    0 2 1 4 5 9 7 8

затем в левой части 2 с 1 и потом вызывается Rotate() для обмена 2 с самим собой. В общем левая часть упорядочивается 

    0 1 2 4 5 9 7 8

а затем фигня. Упорядочивание правой части начинается не с [5 9][7 8], а с [4 5][9 7 8].

--

Вот этот момент в псевокоде я совсем не понимаю

        Symmerge (A, first1, start, m)
    Symmerge (A, m, end, last)

Comment: *Совершенно перестал редактироваться комментарий, все уходит за границу окна (наверное слишком длинный)*. 

--

Так вот, одно и то же **m** в первом и втором вызовах не понимаю. Не понимаю и еще  кое-какие моменты (например, один и то же **end** в Rotate() и втором Symmerge()). IMHO это противоречит алгоритму, описываемому в статье словами. 

Или я чего-то не понимаю в псевдокоде (например, что "очевидные" изменения переменных в нем опускаются) ?

Comment: есть несколько вопросов насчет метода rotate:  
1) сдвиг вправо/влево?  
2) аргументы метода: 1 - массив , 2 - index первого элемента, 3 - количество ротаций, 4 - index последнего элемента ?

Comment: *Rotate (int Array[], int first, int second, int end);*

Вращаем вправо элементы, начиная с индекса **first** и заканчивая индексом **end** так, чтобы элемент, который был **second**, встал на место **first**. Соответственно элемент с индексом **end** окажется на месте **second-1**.

*rotate (int array[], int n_elements, int m);*

Вращаем вправо массив из **n_elements** (т.е. [0..n_elements-1]) вправо **m** раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

заработало, вы уж простите код на java:

```
import java.util.Arrays ;

public class TestMerge
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // define two sorted arrays
        int[] m = new int[] { 0, 2, 5, 9 } ;
        int[] n = new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 8 } ;

        // concat arrays
        int[] both = new int[m.length + n.length] ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < m.length ; i++ )
        {
            both[i] = m[i] ;
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++ )
        {
            both[m.length + i] = n[i] ;
        }

        dump ( both ) ;

        symmerge ( both, 0, m.length, both.length ) ;
    }

    private static void dump ( int[] both )
    {
        System.out.println ( Arrays.toString ( both ) ) ;
    }

    public static void symmerge ( int[] a, int first1, int first2, int last )
    {
        if ( first1 < first2 && first2 < last )
        {
            // m, n
            int m = (first1 + last) / 2 ;
            int n = m + first2 ;

            // start, end
            int start ;
            if ( first2 > m )
            {
                start = bsearch ( a, n - last, m, n - 1 ) ;
            }
            else
            {
                start = bsearch ( a, first1, first2, n - 1 ) ;
            }
            int end = n - start ;

            rotate ( a, start, first2, end - 1 ) ;

            symmerge ( a, first1, start, m ) ;
            symmerge ( a, m, end, last ) ;
        }
    }

    public static int bsearch ( int[] a, int l, int r, int p )
    {
        while ( l < r )
        {
            int m = (l + r) / 2 ;
            if ( a[m] <= a[p - m] )
            {
                l = m + 1 ;
            }
            else
            {
                r = m ;
            }
        }
        return l ;
    }

    public static void rotate ( int[] a, int first, int second, int end )
    {
        if ( first != second )
        {
            int rotation = first - second ;
            if ( rotation < 0 )
            {
                rotation = rotation + (end - first + 1) ;
            }

            // rotate
            rotateImpl ( a, first, end, rotation ) ;
        }
    }

    private static void rotateImpl ( int[] a, int start, int end, int rotation )
    {
        int tmp ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rotation ; i++ )
        {
            tmp = a[end] ;
            for ( int j = end ; j > start ; j-- )
            {
                a[j] = a[j - 1] ;
            }
            a[start] = tmp ;
        }

        dump ( a ) ;
    }
}
```

результат (новая строчка после каждого rotate):

```
[0, 2, 5, 9, 1, 4, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

p.s не стоит забывать что надо соблюдать условие для длинны массивов m >=n

тест с другим набором входных данных:

```
    int[] m = new int[] { 0, 2, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15 } ;
    int[] n = new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11 } ;
```

результат:

```
[0, 2, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11]
[0, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 8, 9, 11]
[0, 2, 1, 5, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 8, 9, 11]
[0, 2, 1, 5, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 8, 9, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 8, 9, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 8, 9, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 13, 15, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 11, 13, 15]
```

Comment: ошибка в вызове метода rotate, еще раз извините за java код, разницу в синтаксисе пытался свести к минимуму

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться. Если не сложно, словами, в чем суть ошибки ?

Ага, увидел. Все таки last это не индекс последнего, а длина 2-х последовательностей (индекс следующего за последним). Значит и end в Rotate() имеет тот же смысл.

Еще раз спасибо, в ближайшее время попробую на C.

Comment: Ну для увеличения скорости можно в rotate определять, в какую сторону крутить меньше.

Comment: Все работает на С. 

Действительно сортировка с этим слиянием работает шустро, на массиве из 1000000 элементов всего в 3 раза медленнее, чем у аналогичной tim_sort (которой требуется дополнительная память). Время работы tim_sort N \* log N, а с слиянием без доп. памяти N \* (log N)^2.

Для массива из 10000000 отставание возросло **всего** до 3.7 раза (!)

Для 100000 время отличается всего в 1.5 раза (!!!).